# Qpid(JMS) - Azure Servicebus - It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, qpid, qpid-proton

We are using qpid-jms-client-0.57.0 to publish and receive messages from Azure ServiceBus.
ServiceBus provides feature to receive message from session to maintain message order.
Please refer here for more details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions

I am able to publish messages with JMXGroupId but not able to receive message from session enabled queue.
Getting error - javax.jms.JMSException: **It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver.** TrackingId:*, SystemTracker:mule-intr-sbus-test-standard:Queue:test-order, Timestamp:2021-07-28T11:07:49 TrackingId:**, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2021-07-28T11:07:49 [condition = amqp:not-allowed]

Could you please suggest anyway to receive messages from session enabled queue?

**Sample Code**

```
public void receiveMessage() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("** Receiver start **");

        Connection connection = createConnection();
        connection.start();

        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Destination destination = session.createQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
        MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
        
        messageConsumer.setMessageListener(this);
        
        System.out.println("** Receiver registered **");
    }
```

**Error Stacktrace**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver. TrackingId:****, SystemTracker:****:Queue:test-order, Timestamp:2021-07-28T10:30:03 TrackingId:****, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2021-07-28T10:30:03 [condition = amqp:not-allowed]
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.ProviderException.toJMSException(ProviderException.java:34)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.exceptions.JmsExceptionSupport.create(JmsExceptionSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.exceptions.JmsExceptionSupport.create(JmsExceptionSupport.java:112)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection.createResource(JmsConnection.java:698)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsMessageConsumer.<init>(JmsMessageConsumer.java:125)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsMessageConsumer.<init>(JmsMessageConsumer.java:82)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsSession.createConsumer(JmsSession.java:479)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsSession.createConsumer(JmsSession.java:467)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsSession.createConsumer(JmsSession.java:459)
    at com.qpid.test.TestSessionEnable.receiveMessage(TestSessionEnable.java:70)
    at com.qpid.test.TestSessionEnable.main(TestSessionEnable.java:80)
Caused by: org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.ProviderException: It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver. TrackingId:****, SystemTracker:****:Queue:test-order, Timestamp:2021-07-28T10:30:03 TrackingId:****, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2021-07-28T10:30:03 [condition = amqp:not-allowed]
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpSupport.convertToNonFatalException(AmqpSupport.java:181)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.builders.AmqpResourceBuilder.getOpenAbortExceptionFromRemote(AmqpResourceBuilder.java:299)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.builders.AmqpResourceBuilder.handleClosed(AmqpResourceBuilder.java:185)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.builders.AmqpResourceBuilder.processRemoteClose(AmqpResourceBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpProvider.processUpdates(AmqpProvider.java:985)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpProvider.onData(AmqpProvider.java:871)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.transports.netty.NettyTcpTransport$NettyTcpTransportHandler.channelRead0(NettyTcpTransport.java:563)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.transports.netty.NettyTcpTransport$NettyTcpTransportHandler.channelRead0(NettyTcpTransport.java:556)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1533)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1282)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1329)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:447)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've asked this and had an answer in the Qpid messaging lists so I guess maybe you weren't happy with the answer but the answer given basically covers the problem.  The Microsoft client is using a illegal filter value which isn't an AMQP described type so even if the client supported somehow setting custom filters (which it doesn't) it wouldn't allow this to be used.

Further the client doesn't expose this level of internal implementation to the user so you can't add any filters to the link attach to leverage whatever this mechanism that Microsoft is enabling with this illegal filter definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim for comment. I raised the issue in parallel to get a quicker response from any user. Happy with Robbie response, so we concluded our requirement based on his input..